# Que pasa si un proceso multihilo no se cierra?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Que tal estoy desarrollando en visual Studio con c#, que pasa si inicio un proceso en otro hilo y despues cierro la aplicacion sin cerrar ese hilo?

El segundo hilo se cierra con la aplicacion? o se mantiene abierto consumiendo memoria

Comment: Se mantiene abierto, ejecutándose hasta que apagues el equipo, los hilos son procesos independientes a los procesos que los crearon.

Comment: en realidad depende de como lo lances.. si es un background no, se va a apagar junto con el principal...